# Handle empty columns in polars when concatenating dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-polars

I want to be able to concatenate dataframes in `polars` where the dataframes have the same columns, but some of the dataframes have no data for a subset of the columns.

More precisely, I am looking for the `polars` equivalent of this `pandas` minimal working example:

```py
from io import StringIO
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd 

TESTDATA1 = StringIO("""
    col1,col2,col3
    1,1,"a"
    2,1,"b"
"""
)

TESTDATA2 = StringIO("""
    col1,col2,col3
    1,,"a"
    2,,"b"
"""
)

df = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.read_csv(TESTDATA1),
        pd.read_csv(TESTDATA2),
    ],
)
print(df)
```

This prints

```
       col1  col2 col3
0         1   1.0    a
1         2   1.0    b
0         1   NaN    a
1         2   NaN    b
```

I tried the following `polars` implementation which does not work for me:

```py
TESTDATA1 = StringIO("""
    col1,col2,col3
    1,1,"a"
    2,1,"b"
""")

TESTDATA2 = StringIO("""
    col1,col2,col3
    1,,"a"
    2,,"b"
""")

df = pl.concat(
    [
        pl.read_csv(TESTDATA1),
        pl.read_csv(TESTDATA2),
    ],
    how ="diagonal"
)
```

I get the error message:

```
SchemaError: cannot vstack: because column datatypes (dtypes) in the two DataFrames do not match for left.name='col2' with left.dtype=i64 != right.dtype=str with right.name='col2'
```

It seems that the empty column is treated as `str` in `polars` and can't be merged with the other dataframe where it is of type `i64`.

I understand that this is a solution for my problem:

```py
df = pl.concat(
    [
        pl.read_csv(TESTDATA1),
        pl.read_csv(TESTDATA2).with_columns(pl.col("col2").cast(pl.Int64)),
    ],
    how ="diagonal"
)
```

But in reality, I have some twenty columns that are potentially `null` and I don't want to cast all of them.

What works in `pandas` and `polars` is the situation where the empty column is removed from the dataframe, i.e.

```py
TESTDATA1 = StringIO("""
    col1,col2,col3
    1,1,"a"
    2,1,"b"
""")

TESTDATA2 = StringIO("""
    col1,col3
    1,"a"
    2,"b"
""")

pl.concat(
    [
        pl.read_csv(TESTDATA1),
        pl.read_csv(TESTDATA2),
    ],
    how ="diagonal"
)
```

In `pandas`, I could also drop the empty column by calling `.dropna(how="all",axis=1)` but I don't know the equivalent for this in `polars`.

So, to **summarize**:

- How can I concatenate dataframes in `polars` if some of them have columns with no data (`null`)?
- How can I achieve the equivalent of `.dropna(how="all",axis=1)` in `polars`?

Thanks!

Comment: Just want to point out that I believe the answer from @Sukant Jha is generated by ChatGPT.

Answer (score 2):

This is supported natively as of Polars version [`0.19.8`](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/11597) with the `diagonal_relaxed` concat strategy.

```py
pl.concat(
    [
        pl.read_csv(TESTDATA1),
        pl.read_csv(TESTDATA2),
    ],
    how = "diagonal_relaxed"
)
```

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ str  ┆ str  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 1    ┆ a    │
│ 2    ┆ 1    ┆ b    │
│ 1    ┆ null ┆ a    │
│ 2    ┆ null ┆ b    │
└──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This would however imply that I am not able to use laziness, is that correct?

Comment: You could use `.scan_csv()` instead of `.concat(pl.read_csv())`

Comment: I've changed the answer to just use `.scan_csv()` instead. You can access the `.schema` from each lazyframe and generate the "supertypes" schema that way. It feels like there should be a simpler way to do this - hopefully someone can let us know.

Comment: Thanks! That helps. Could `df.select(col for col in df if col.is_not_null().any())` also work the lazy way?

Comment: I don't think so, no. `.is_not_null().any()` could not be known without reading all the data.